# Classify elements from a list to another classification

Tags: c#, oop

I''ve got a `List<Foo>`. Foo class contains a Type property. Type property is a enum.

```
  public enum Type
  {
       Arithmetic, Fraction, ...
  }


  public class Foo
  {
      public Type ProblemType
      {
          get; set;
      }
  }
```

I'd like to generate another list where it is sorted by ProblemType, and each one contains Foo clases which belong to the same Type. I can imagine I should use Enumerable, but I don't know how use them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want a list of lists, where each inner list contains `Foo`s with the same `ProblemType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GroupBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) to do that:

```
List<List<Foo>> groupedLists
    = yourList.GroupBy(foo => foo.ProblemType)
              .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
              .Select(group => group.ToList())
              .ToList();
```

In passing, I would advise against using `Type` as the name of your enum, as getting into name conflicts with [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) is usually not a good idea. You can even name it `ProblemType`, since writing `public ProblemType ProblemType { get; set; }` is unambiguous.

Comment: If you first order and then select, you could use the `Key` property of the grouping. I think it's clearer than using `First()`.

Comment: @svick, you're absolutely right. Answer updated accordingly, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To sort by `ProblemType`, you can try this

```
var sortedFooList = fooList.OrderBy(f => f.ProblemType);
```

`sortedFooList` will be `IOrderedEnumerable<Foo>`. If you want `List<Foo>`, just add `.ToList()` after calling `OrderBy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a `List<Foo>`, you can query that list to provide an ordered collection by ProblemType:

```
List<Foo> myFoos = GetFooList();

var sortedFoos = myFoos.OrderBy(f => f.ProblemType);
```

`sortedFoos` is an enumerated collection sorted by Foo.ProblemType.